# How check for UI object while long-pressed in UI Automator

Tags: android, testing, android-uiautomator

I'm testing an app which shows a UI element Only when some other UI is long pressed. Once the user removes the finger/mouse, the UI element is gone.

How can I test the same in UI automator? I managed to long click but it seems that once the statement is executed, it behaves as if the finger is removed.

In short, I want to long press => check if element exists => remove finger (no more pressed). How can I attain the same in UI automator?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can sleep the thread for few seconds and check with different thread if UI Element exists or not.

Comment: How can that be done? I tried using `preformTaskAndWait()` But it requires `EventCondition`. As we can't make custom EventCondition, and there are just 2 of them provided by the library, I can't use that either.

I'm also trying to use `wait()` with `Until.findObject(By.text("name"))` but even that is not working.

Comment: If you can provide some code, I can try it and share the answer.